# How do I insert a javascript variable into a model in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to save the longitude and latitude of a user to a model to use with various API's for things like traffic and weather and what not. I get the users latitude and longitude by using the navigator.geolocation that is in html5. What is the best way to save this info to a UserProfile model?

I've tried setting up a form to use but can't get anything to work with the check box I have that enables geolocation. I've also thought of using ajax but don't know how to pass the data to the model in django.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                getLocation()
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                console.log("Location services are disabled");
            }
        });
    });
  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
      console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
    function showPosition(position) {
        console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        var latlon = (position.coords.latitude + ','+ position.coords.longitude)
        console.log(latlon)

    };
```

This is what I'm using to get the location of the user, it's in a profile.html page I have set up for the user. I'm new to Django and coding in general as well as stackoverflow, so if I need to include more or less, or should ask this in a different way, please let me know!

Comment: Does your `UserProfile` have some sort of model fields that are supposed to keep that information?

Comment: yes it has a field that is for the latitude/longitude that is empty by default

Comment: And the `UserProfile` has a foreign key to `User` with a `related_name` ?

Comment: yes I extended the default Django User model to make the UserProfile

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following user model:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

specified in settings with

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "theapp.UserProfile"
```

we need to create a view that handles it:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from .models import UserProfile

class UserView(DetailView):
    template_name = "profile.html"
    model = UserProfile
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        profile = self.get_object()
        lat = request.POST.get("latitude")
        long = request.POST.get("longitude")

        if lat is None or long is None:
            return HttpResponse()

        profile.latitude = float(lat)
        profile.longitude = float(long)
        profile.save()

        return HttpResponse()
```

And then the template like:

```
<div>
    <strong>Current lat: </strong> {{ profile.latitude }}<br/>
    <strong>Current long: </strong> {{ profile.longitude }}<br/><br/>
</div>

<label for="locations-status">Locations enabled?</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="locations-status">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var PROFILE_ID = {{ profile.id }};

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                getLocation()
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                console.log("Location services are disabled");
            }
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        var latlon = (position.coords.latitude + ','+ position.coords.longitude);

        $.post({
            url: "{% url 'profile-detail' profile.id %}",
            data: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            }
        });

        console.log(latlon);
    };
</script>
```

Notice the extra csrftoken javascript functionality.

This is just one way to do it. There are better ways of course by using the [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org)